# Why getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward() dont work with JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I try to redirect my page to another using `request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);` . But it dont work. Why? But when I change it to `response.sendRedirect` it work fine.

Comment: what is the error message you see?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be because of not using relative url.

You can try like this

`request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you do need the forward slash with the JSP filename.

This is just a small possibility (need more info) - but do you have an init() method in your servlet?

If you do, you must call super.init(servletConfig) as the first line of your init() method, or you might get a NullPointerException when you try to forward.